# ¿Cómo conjugo verbos con el pronombre indefinido "One"?

Tags: pronombres, tiempos-verbales, conjugación

#### Español

En inglés, algunas personas usan el pronombre indefinido "[One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun))" (uno).

- Véase la versión en inglés de la pregunta para ejemplos.

Normalmente, se usa esta palabra cuando quiere uno ser formal y para evitar el uso de la segunda persona "you" (tú).

¿Cómo uso esta construcción en español?

**Específicamente, ¿cómo conjugo verbos con el pronombre indefinido "one?"**

---

#### English

In English, some people use the indefinite pronoun "One."

- Example: One does not eat bread without butter.
- Example: How does one bake a cake?

Typically, they use this word when they want to be formal and to avoid using the second-person "you."

How do I use this approach in Spanish?

**Specifically, how do I conjugate verbs when I use the indefinite pronoun "one?"**

Comment: As an aside, you can also use the impersonal 2nd person in Spanish, just as in English. Though I understand this is not what you are asking about.

Comment: One does not simply walk into Mordor.

Comment: @fedorqui Intenté! Gracias por tus ediciones!

Answer (score 8):

A pesar de que se puede usar *uno* tal y como en inglés (y así usando la 3.ª singular del verbo), como debe de ser obvio por el primer verbo en esta oración, el español te permite usar el verbo en forma pronominal, llamado el *pasivo impersonal*, con este significado.  Por tanto, los ejemplos que tienes se los puede (jeje) traducir como lo siguiente:

> - No se come el pan sin mantequilla
> - ¿Cómo se hace un pastel?

Pero cuidado: el *pasivo impersonal* es *siempre* en tercera personal singular.  Nota la pequeña diferencia entre estas dos frases:

> - Se puede traducir las palabras fácilmente.
> - Se pueden traducir las palabras fácilmente.

El primero es impersonal, y se interpreta como el inglés *One can translate...* mientras el otro es el *pasivo reflejo* y aproxima la voz media y en inglés se traduce normalmente usando la voz pasiva: *The words are easily translated*.  Si el sujeto es singular, a veces es difícil si no imposible saber cuál es cuál, pero como el significado de ambos en tal caso es bastante parecida, no hay problema.

Comment: Estuve pensando que la forma impersonal de decir *uno tiene que hacer X* es *hay que hacer X* (*se tiene que hacer X* es posible pero suena muy poco natural, ¿no?).

Comment: La frase   *se puede traducir las palabras fácilmente* suena mal y creo que está mal. Cuando el CD es cosa debería usarse la pasiva refleja y el verbo iría en plural en este caso: http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables

Comment: @pablodf76 sí, pero más por costumbre que por gramática, de hecho, buscando en Google, hay una canción que se llama «Como se tiene que hacer»

Comment: @pablodf76 seguro no suena natural en algunas partes. Aquí en Colombia es muy común usarlo. p.ej _Uno no come pan sin mantequilla_ suena perfectamente natural para nosotros.

Comment: @blonfu lo del DPD es una recomendación, la Nueva Gramática explica los pormenores. Luego pondré más información si lo quieres, pero creo que anteponiendo *las palabras* puede aclararlo algo: una frase como «Las palabras se las puede traducir fácilmente» (*alguien/uno puede traducirlas*) tiene un significado que es ligeramente diferente de «Las palabras se pueden traducir fácilmente» (*son fácilmente traducibles*), pero una estructura más evidente

Comment: @guifa será como dices, a mi me suena muy raro la verdad, ¿quizá en otros países suene mas natural? Yo soy de España

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways of expressing "one" as in "How should one greet a professor at the grocery store?"

1. A passive (reflexive) construction: *¿Cómo se debe saludar al profesor en el súper?* Note that this is similar to English "How should the professor be greeted in the grocery store?"
2. With "uno", which is conjugated in the third person singular (like "el" and "ella"): *¿Cómo debe uno saludar al profe en la tienda?*
3. Sometimes with "hay que", for example: "One should be polite with newcomers," *Hay que ser cortés con los nuevos [principiantes]*.  Note, this one shows a stronger requirement than the other expressions. It has the same feeling as "one must etc."
4. Sometimes with "tu" (conjugated as second person singluar) or "usted" (conjugated as third person singular), for example: "On Fridays one can wear jeans at our office," *Tú puedes / Ud. puede usar pantalón de mezclilla los viernes aquí.*  Note, the subject pronoun may be omitted.
5. With "conviene" (*convenir*) or "recomendable", for example: "One should leave the kitchen clean for the next person," *Es recomendable dejar la cocina limpia para la próxima persona*; "one should write down the homework assignments," *conviene anotar las tareas.*  This is similar to the English "It is a good idea to write down the assignments," or "It's worthwhile to tiptoe if you come in after 11" (which could also be "It's best to tiptoe etc.").

Comment: +1 Opino que esta respuesta es la más completa :)